# How to differentiate between 2 identical 1TB hard drives?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a system with Linux Mint and Windows 10 installed on it. My Windows 10 side has the boot drive on a 60gb partition of a 120gb SSD, with the data drive on a 1TB
HDD (this has all my data on it). My Mint side also has the boot drive on a 60gb partition of a 120gb SSD, with the `/home` partition on a different 1TB HDD (the data on this one can be deleted). I need to replace Mint with Ubuntu, but I want to make sure I don't overwrite my data on Windows 10 data drive. Last time I did this 
I guessed and picked the wrong one and lost some files, and I don't want that to happen again. Is there a way I can differentiate between the two hard drives?

Comment: Yes you can check the serial number of the hard drives

Comment: @ARG can I find that in GParted?

Comment: @calthecoder yes, you can use gparted

Comment: If you use the Something Else install option, the installer should tell you if a system is installed in some partitions. So you should see Windows and Mint. Then just choose (change button) the Mint partition, check format  & ext4 and use as / (root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your disk is smart enabled, you can get a lot of information with `smartctl`:

```
$ smartctl -i /dev/sda
```

If all you want is the drive's serial number, you can filter it:

```
$ smartctl -i /dev/sda | grep -i serial
```

Substitute `/dev/sda` by the name of your devices.